# How many maximum depedent types are supported?

Tags: c++

This is just my curiosity to understand more about C++ behavior. It's somehow not realistic.
As I know for template it could be declared with a type which depends on another type
For example `vector<T>` T can be any type and so T can continue depending on something else. So when will it end up with a limit such as an error raised by compiler ??
This also has the same understanding as recursive function
Anyway I might be wrong

Comment: This is most likely implementation specific and you may run out of system memory before the compiler gives up. If you want to test your implementation, why not make a generator that generates programs with ever-longer chains and compiles them in a loop? With some compilers, you may run into a symbol name length limit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007568/what-is-max-length-for-an-c-c-identifier-on-common-build-systems

Comment: That’s not language specific but would fully depend on a specific compiler and version of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ standard does not set a limit for template recursion depth, but it does recommend a minimum limit of 1024.

Some code (e.g. Boost Spirit, PyBind) can approach this limit with complicated grammars or Python bindings. You could also attain it trivially with some metaprogramming.

With GCC, you can control the recursion limit by passing

```
-ftemplate-depth=X
```